# Copy Database from Production to Development

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I need to copy database from production to development instance in SQL Server 2012 as I don't want to mess up the production server database.

Can someone suggest how I can do this ?

Comment: 1-Take backup from production and restore it on development server or 2-Use copy database built in feature

Comment: I don't have a permissions to restore database. is it safe to use copy database ?

Comment: Be sure to remove any sensitive information, such as credit card numbers or phone numbers etc.

Comment: when i am trying to restore i am getting this below error ."NO Backupset selected to be restored"

Answer (score 3):

Backup from PROD `with COPY_ONLY, compression` and restore it on DEV server is the best option.

Make sure to enable [Instant File initialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sql_pfe_blog/how-and-why-to-enable-instant-file-initialization) to cut down the restore time.

**Edit:**

> I don't have a permissions to restore database. is it safe to use copy database ?

This might imply that you are not authorized to do such operation. You can ask your DBA to help you out once you have put in a proper support ticket.

Also, its quiet important to wipe out [PII information](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2409/identifying-pii-data-to-lock-down-in-sql-server-part-1-of-2/) when you do a restore on a NON PROD system - as @MichaelGreen pointed out.